# How to iterate rows and check for multiple changes in column?

Tags: python, pandas

I have multiple columns in my data frame but three columns are important.

| id | Date | Answer |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 12222 | 2020-05-01 | N |
| 12222 | 2020-05-02 | Y |
| 12222 | 2020-05-03 | N |
| 12222 | 2020-05-04 | Y |
| 12223 | 2020-05-06 | Y |
| 12224 | 2020-05-07 | Y |
| 12224 | 2020-05-08 | Y |
| 12225 | 2020-05-09 | N |
| 12225 | 2020-05-09 | Y |

For each id that have multiple changes in their answer I need to find and count that change in a separate column  N -> Y is a change or Y->N but it has to be for the same id.

Therefore N->Y->N->Y would be 3 changes.
N->Y->N->N is only two changes.

I have sorted the data frame in ascending order using the below code and tried to do a count but only getting a count of the number of values, responding to that id rather than changes.

```
df_changes = df.sort_values(by=['id', 'Date'], ascending =[True,True])
df_changes_2 = df_changes.groupby(['id','answer']).size().reset_index(name="Count")
```

Possible Output:

| id | Date | Answer | Count |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 12222 | 2020-05-01 | N | 3 |
| 12223 | 2020-05-06 | Y | 0 |
| 12224 | 2020-05-07 | Y | 0 |
| 12225 | 2020-05-09 | N | 1 |

Answer (score 0):

I think this can help you find the solution you need.

```py
import pandas as pd

d = {'id' : ['12222', '12222', '12222', '12222', '12223', '12224', '12224', '12225', '12225']
,'Date' : ['2020-05-01', '2020-05-02', '2020-05-02', '2020-05-03', '2020-05-02', '2020-05-02', '2020-05-02', '2020-05-02', '2020-05-02'],
'Answer' : ['N', 'Y', 'N','Y', 'N', 'Y', 'Y', 'N', 'Y']}

df = pd.DataFrame(data = d)



col_ANSW = df['Answer'].tolist()
col_ID = df['id'].tolist()
cont = -1
y = ''
z = ''
cont_as = []
for x in range(0, len(col_ANSW)):
    
    if ((col_ID[x] != z) and (x > 1)):
        cont_as.append((str(col_ID[x]),str(cont)))
        cont = -1
    else:
        cont_as.append((str(col_ID[x]),'0'))
    if (col_ANSW[x] != y):
        cont += 1
    y = col_ANSW[x]
    z = col_ID[x]
    
cont_as.append((str(col_ID[x]),str(cont)))
cont_as = pd.DataFrame(cont_as, columns = ['id','CONT'])
cont_as = cont_as.set_index('id')
df = pd.merge(df, cont_as, how = 'left', on = 'id')

print(str(df))
```

Comment: This doesn't give the correct output it just counts the, just the occurrence once.

Comment: Do you want to group in a dictionary or in a column and if it is a column, how do you want to group that count in a column?

Comment: It should be in a column to be grouped by the customer id and checking the dates are correct order but the count should be of the difference in changes, as mentioned above

Comment: I made some changes, now it counts by id and stores it in a variable (id, changes), it would be possible to have a print of how you want to structure this column, because I didn't understand your explanation

Comment: The cont_as is correct but is it possible to place it inside the same data frame?

Comment: yes, but it depends on how you want to put this value in the columns

Comment: I have updated it to show the required output should be in the same dafaframe if possible with the most recent  date.

Comment: I changed the code but I don't know why it doubles when 'merging', but it would be more or less that

Answer (score 0):

You can try `transform` then `drop_duplicates`

```py
df['Count'] = df.groupby('id', as_index=False)['Answer'].transform(lambda col: col.ne(col.shift()).sum() - 1)
```

```
print(df)

      id        Date Answer  Count
0  12222  2020-05-01      N      3
1  12222  2020-05-02      Y      3
2  12222  2020-05-03      N      3
3  12222  2020-05-04      Y      3
4  12223  2020-05-06      Y      0
5  12224  2020-05-07      Y      0
6  12224  2020-05-08      Y      0
7  12225  2020-05-09      N      1
8  12225  2020-05-09      Y      1
```

```
df = df.drop_duplicates('id', keep='first')
```

```
print(df)

      id        Date Answer  Count
0  12222  2020-05-01      N      3
4  12223  2020-05-06      Y      0
5  12224  2020-05-07      Y      0
7  12225  2020-05-09      N      1
```

Comment: Perfect, just wondering for a larger dataset is this slower?

Comment: @Nero_Oke Not sure, but group by is kind of slow.